# Error message in output won't close in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My code caught an error in VS Code and I could not delete or close it. I tried Clear All Output but it didn't work. What happened and how can I close it?

[image]

Comment: Are you getting like an infinite loop?

Comment: @toRex No, that's the end of the error message. I was trying to generate a 3d plot.

Comment: What have you done that the error is generated? [example] please.

Comment: @user202729 I might have accidentally plotted a 3d `go.Surface` plot with error code. Something like `fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(my_array)])`

Answer (score 0):

Restarted VS Code and laptop and got rid of the error.